# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'child' of null

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been getting this error on my project, so suspecting some change on firebase side I created a fresh new nativescript project, fresh new firebase project with fresh new android app, adding fresh database data, still getting the same error.

Essentially all `firebase.instance` inside `nativescript-plugin-firebase` plugin are null all of a sudden without any change in code from my side

Essentially all `firebase.instance` inside `nativescript-plugin-firebase` plugin are null all of a sudden without any change in code from my side.

**Error Message Received on terminal:**

> JS: Error in firebase.addValueEventListener: TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'child' of null JS: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise):
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'child' of null JS: TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'child' of null JS:     at
>   file:///data/data/org.nativescript.bbnsng/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.js:1456:24
>   JS:     at new ZoneAwarePromise
>   (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.bbnsng/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:776:29)
>   JS:     at Object.firebase.addValueEventListener
>   (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.bbnsng/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.js:1444:10)
>   JS:     at Observable._subscribe
>   (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.bbnsng/files/app/modules/services/firebase.service.js:23:22)
>   JS:     at Observable._trySubscribe
>   (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.bbnsng/files/app/tns_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:57:25)
>   JS:     at Observable.subscribe
>   (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.bbnsng/files/app/tns_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:45:27)
>   JS:     at Observable.ConnectableObservable.connect
>   (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.bbnsng/files/app/tns_modules/rxjs/observable/ConnectableObservable.js:37:18)
>   JS:     at RefCountOperator.call
>   (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.bbnsng/files/app/tns_modules/rxjs/observable/ConnectableObservable.js:101:49)
>   JS:     at Observable.subscribe
>   (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.bbnsng/files/app/tns_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:42:22)
>   JS:     at ObservableStrategy.createSubscription
>   (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.bbnsng/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js:2664:22)
>   JS:     at AsyncPipe._subscribe
>   (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.bbnsng/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js:2778:45)
>   JS:     at AsyncPipe.transform
>   (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.bbnsng/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js:2755:22)
>   JS:     at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]
>   (ng:///HomeModule/HomeComponent.ngfactory.js:127:68) JS:     at
>   Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives]
>   (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.bbnsng/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12613:21)
>   JS:     at checkAndUpdateView
>   (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.bbnsng/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12025:14)

**Steps I followed:**

- Create a new repo
- Create a new firebase project in firebase console
- Create an android app under that probject with Package name `org.nativescript.bbnsng`
- Run `keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/bbnsng.keystore` to get SHA1, update app with same
- Add some data to database and make permission rules public
- Code up the corresponsding nativescript angular app to this state https://github.com/ishandutta2007/bb_ns_ng_main_app2
- downloaded `google-services.json` and add it to app/App_Resources/Android/
- Run the app.

**Steps to reproduce:**

`git clone https://github.com/ishandutta2007/bb_ns_ng_main_app2.git
cd bb_ns_ng_main_app2
tns run android`

Answer (score 0):

For me, adding following statement to app.js/app.ts fixed this issue provided I have correct firebase database configured. For Example:

```
require("./shared/firebase/firebase.common");
```

For Angular Project, add import firebase.common in main.ts. For example:

```
import "./shared/firebase/firebase.common";
```